# Managing foreign keys when using pg_restore with multiple dumps

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, cloning, pg-restore

I have a bit of a weird issue. We were trying to create a database baseline for our local environment that has very specific data pre-seeded into it. Our hopes were to make sure that everyone was operating with the same data, making collaboration and reviewing code a bit simpler.

My idea for this was to run a command to dump the database whenever we run a migration or decide a new account is necessary for local dev. The issue with this is the database dump is around 17MB. I'm trying to avoid us having to add a 17MB file to GitHub every time we update the database.

So the best solution I could think of was to setup a script to dump each individual table in the database. This way, if a single table is updated, we'd only be pushing that backup to GitHub and it would be more along a ~200kb file as opposed to 17mb.

The main issue I'm running into with this is trying to restore the database. With a full dump, handling the foreign keys is relatively simple as it's all done in a single restore command. But with multiple restores, it gets a bit more complicated.

I'm looking to find a way to restore all tables to a database, ignoring triggers and constraints, and then enabling them again once the data has been populated. (or find a way to export the tables based on the order the foreign keys are defined). There are a lot of tables to work with, so doing this manually would be a bit of a task.

I'm also concerned about the relational integrity of the database if I disabled/re-enable constraints. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Right now I'm running the following on every single table:

```
pg_dump postgres://user:password@pg:5432/database -t table_name -Fc -Z9 -f /data/www/database/data/table_name.bak
```

And then this command to restore all backups to the DB.

```
$data_command = "pg_restore --disable-triggers -d $dbUrl -Fc \"%s\"";
$backups = glob("$directory*.bak");
    foreach($backups as $data_file){
        if($data_file != 'data_roles.bak') {
            exec(sprintf($data_command, $data_file));
        }
    }
```

This obviously doesn't work as I hit a ton of "Relationship doesn't exist" errors. I guess I'm just looking for a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would separate the table data and the database metadata.

Create a pre- and post-data scfipt with

```
pg_dump --section=pre-data -f pre.sql mydb
pg_dump --section=post-data -f post.sql mydb
```

Then dump just the data for each table:

```
pg_dump --section=data --table=tab1 -f tab1.sql mydb
```

To restore the database, first restore `pre.sql`, then all the table data, then `post.sql`.

The pre- and post-data will change often, but they are not large, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: And how to restore?

Comment: @user1735921 As it says in the documentation: for a plain format dump like my answer shows, you use `psql` to restore. For all other formats, use `pg_restore`.

Comment: ok got it.......

Comment: Another variant of this could be to run `pg_dump --schema-only source_db | psql target_db && pg_dump --data-only source_db | psql target_db`